# PHP Preg_Match alphanumeric, special characters and white space - textarea field

Tags: php, forms, preg-match, alphanumeric

I have a product upload form and 1 of the fields is a product description which is basically a textarea field. Everything about the form work except for even after you fill it out it won't go to the database because I keep getting an error for the "product description" field. It's saying that according to the preg_match I'm putting in the wrong characters. Right now the preg_match is allowing only letters and white space but for some reason it's not going through. However, I need the preg_match to allow letters, numbers, white space and special characters. Can someone help me write a preg_match that allows all 4 of these and also tell me why it's not working right now as is. Below is the code.

```
if (empty($productDescr)) {
        $productDescrError = "Product Description is required";
        echo "<strong>" .$productDescrError."</strong><br/>";
        $hasError = true;
    } // line closes if statement
        else {
            $productDescr = test_input($_POST["productDescr"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-z][-\'a-z]+[a-z]$/i",$productDescr)) {
                $productDescrError = "Only letters and white space allowed in <em>Product Description</em>";
                echo "<strong>" .$productDescrError."</strong><br/>";
                $hasError = true;
        } // line closes if statement
    } // line closes else statement
```

Comment: Your pattern `^[a-z][-\'a-z]+[a-z]$` allows no whitespaces and requires a minumum of 3 characters. It should start and end with a lowercase a-z and allows 1 or more times `a-z`, `'` or `-` in between. Can you update your question with examples that you do and do not want to allow?

Comment: You probably want to test if characters that are NOT the characters `/[^-a-z' ]/i` are found.  Maybe add more, your current pattern doesn't allow for `,. ' "` etc.  Then remove the `!` from the `preg_match`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I don't see where I can update my question so I'll put my details here. I want the product description where the person can input letters, numbers, white space and special characters such as a comma, period, etc.

Comment: You want _letters_, _numbers_, _spaces_ and WHAT special characters?  Just `-` and `'`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I want letters, numbers, spaces, commas, periods, question marks, all symbols. Basically everything because you never know how a user may describe the product he or she is uploading.

Comment: Then the question is,  what do you **NOT** want???

Comment: @AbraCadaver I just want to check to make sure it's really legit characters being entered and that no one isn't trying to inject bad code into this field or hack it any kind of way. I'm trying to put some form of a security feature on it.

Comment: @Aishah91I think AbraCadaver is right. The question is what do you NOT want. Protecting against all kind of evil input is not really feasible with just doing one regex, especially if it (as you request) just allows everything. That would be the same as just not having any check at all. Define what you want to block and put according counter measures in place.

Comment: @ArSeN Ok I see what you're saying. Thank you.